# Подскажите пожалуйста библиотеку View для Android

Tags: android

Искал в гугле, толком не нашел что надо.

Проблема состоит в том что я хотел узнать есть ли в Android библиотека которая включает в себя, популярные view компоненты у которых по мимо стандартных атрибутов. Есть еще и такие атрибуты как радиус углов. border, добавление иконки. Указание размера иконки, положение иконки.

TextView
ImageView
Button

Потому что как я понимаю. От Google этого не дождаться. Возможно лет через 10 они это сделают....

Comment: гугл дали инструменты, для создания любых вью, зачем им делать частные случаи? попробуйте поискать на android arsenal. там есть библиотеки на любой вкус и цвет ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"**радиус углов. border**" - это все есть, вот примеры:
http://developer.alexanderklimov.ru/android/theory/shape.php

"**добавление иконки**" - для этого есть параметры android:drawableBottom,
        android:drawableLeft,
        android:drawableRight,
        android:drawableTop.

Если Вам этого будет не достаточно, заходите на https://github.com, и подбирайте то, что Вам по душе. Ну а еще, Вы всегда можете создать свой кастомный Вью ;)